# UITableView reloads data twice, but does not show data properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am calling two webservices and I am displaying both content in one tableview. Since I am calling asynchronously, I would like to load data whichever comes in first and call again when the second service finishes. Response from those services are inserted in their own separate sections and therefore I am saving them in their respective NSarrays.

A -> TO Web Service -> tableView reloadData whenever response arrives

B -> To Web Service -> tableView reloadData whenever response arrives

```
-(void)UpdateTable{

    if (_firstRequest  || _secondRequest){
        runningRefresh = false;
       [self.tableView reloadData];
        [self removeLoading];
    }

}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else if (section == 1){
        if (!_firstRequest){
            return 1;
        }else{
            NSLog(@"SECTION 1");
            if ([self._collectionsNewGame isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || [self._collectionsNewGame count] == 0){
                NSLog(@"0 COUNT");
                return 0;
            }
            NSLog(@"%ld COUNT",[self._collectionsNewGame count]);
            return [self._collectionsNewGame count] + 1;
        }

    }
    else if (section == 2){
        if (!_thirdRequest){
            return 1;
        }else{
            if ([self._collectionsRandom isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || [self._collectionsRandom count] == 0){
                return 0;
            }
            return [self._collectionsRandom count] + 1;
        }

    }
    else return 0;
     //count number of row from counting array hear cataGorry is An Array
}
```

I am just reading in cellrowatindexpath and displaying it.

But, when I do this, there are rows where cells are not showing up and acting weirdly. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: You need to provide more code. Specifically we need to see the `UITableViewDataSource` methods that provide the cells.

Comment: Start the name with a lowercase letter and capitalize the first letter of embedded words. [Apple Coding Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html)

Answer (score 0):

Consolidate the response of those services in one single data source lets say an `NSArray` if what you want is only to add rows to your `UITableView` instead of using `reloadData` insert the rows where needed with `insertRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation :`. Make sure you have the right validations

[Here is the apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html)

Finally use the main queue to perform the `UITableview` updates

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateTable) 
                   withObject:object 
                waitUntilDone:YES]
```

By passing `YES` to `waitUntilDone` you are blocking the main thread the method has completed.

In the same manner you can use

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [self updateTable];
}];
```

The difference is that this approach doesn't guarantee when `updateTable` will be executed. There could be other items in that queue still waiting to execute.

Comment: My question was not very clear and i am sorry for that. Response from those services are inserted in their own separate sections and therefore I am saving them in their respective NSarrays. I am not sure how to use your solution in this scenario?

Comment: The problem you are facing is that you are updating your tableview asynchronously this means that while the service A is done is in the middle of a tableview update there is no lock for the tableView so it can end the update and then start any update from the next service. Now if u are using two different arrays how are you handling the logic in your UITableViewDataSource methods?? Will be so much useful if you can share that code so we can understand that.

Comment: Now remember that `reloadData` removes all the `UITableViewCell` views from the table. The data source delegate methods are called when the table is repainted. So, it's an asynchronous task but some methods are called synchronous so the number of sections & rows and row heights are updated immediately.

Comment: This is my first app and therefore I didn't know that reloadData removes all the cell. I have added my number of rows section hopefully that helps you understand what i am doing

Comment: First thing I see is you are using `NSNull` to check your `NSArray`, Accordingly to Apple, The `NSNull` class defines a singleton object you use to represent null values in situations where nil is prohibited as a value (typically in a collection object such as an array or a dictionary). The `NSNull` instance is semantically equivalent to `nil`, however it is also important to appreciate that it is not equal to `nil`. See more here [Using NSNull](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Null.html)

Comment: So you say you have two service calls, in `updateTable` I don't see any validation for `_thirdRequest ` I would like to know from where are you calling  `updateTable` also noticed that when you don't have data in your arrays u are returning 1 in `table:numberOfRowsInSection: ` that for sure will cause to have an empty cell if you have data to work with.

Comment: I have two web service call in view did load and inside the completion block (which stores response in an array) it calls update Table. Each section has a header, thats why i am returning 1 which displays that request is still in progress to the user. When I call reloadData once by checking both requests are complete, it work fine but when i do reloadData twice, i have cells that are getting removed as i am scrolling